# what is the sql query for combination

Tags: sql, join, etl, teradata

I recently had an iterview. I was asked a complex sql question. I was not able to answer it.

Q: There are 8 teams in football match.

case1: Each team has to play with one another but only once.

Case2: Each team has to play with another team twice.

Could you please tell me the SQl query for both the cases?

Comment: Please, add your table definitions and what have you tried this far and how your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first query you can do:

```
select a.*, b.*
from team a
join team b on a.id < b.id
```

For the second one, you can do:

```
select a.*, b.*
from team a
join team b on a.id <> b.id
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I do have one confusion regarding the filter condition(a.id <b.id) and a.id <>b.id. Since we are using self join for a table. So, all the values of id are same right between the tables.So, how can that condition gives us the result? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @soulshrestha The first solution will show cases team A plays against team B, but not B against A. The second will show both (A-B and B-A). That's why it works.

Comment: Thank You very much I got the result as expected with the query you mentioned. But one question, I  am using my SQL tool and when i use the count keyword to get the count of the join condition. I am not able to get the result. But I can get the count of the individual table. The query is below:select count(*) from (select t1.name, t2.name
from teams t1
inner join teams t2 on t1.id <> t2.id); I am not getting any  result for me. Could you please help me.

Comment: @soulshrestha You can just use `COUNT(*)` as in: `select count(*) from team a join team b on a.id < b.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a table called `teams` with columns `id` and `name`, you can self-join the table.

Q2 is about generating all combinations of teams - excepted that a team can't play against itself:

```
select t1.name, t2.name
from teams t1
inner join teams t2 on t1.id <> t2.id
```

For Q1, you can use an inequality condition so each tuple appears just once:

```
select t1.name, t2.name
from teams t1
inner join teams t2 on t1.id < t2.id
```

Comment: Thank you.I got the result as expected.